# iOS auto-layout misplaced views off-by-one bug

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two buttons which should take up half the width of the view, each.

I have:

- leading-space constraint on the left-hand button to the superview
- trailing-space constraint on the left-hand button to the right-hand button
- trailing-space constraint on the right-hand button to the superview
- equal-width constraint on the buttons

I get misplaced views:

```
Button 1 
  Expected: width=161 
  Actual: width=160

Button 2 
  Expected: width=161 
  Actual: width=160
```

I get the same with the vertical.

Surely, 320 / 2 = 160, right? Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Or should I just ignore the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Misplaced views really seem to be more suggestions than requirements. Unless constraints are breaking, you probably have nothing to worry about.

If you want the warning to go away, try selecting "Update Constraints", as maybe they are missing an extra pixel in their addition to fill the screen.

Comment: "Update Constraints" does not change anything. I agree that it is not breaking. I am curious why a simple layout with exact pixel (point) values should cause issues. For example, dividing the Retina 3.5 inch form factor into 4 equal spaces with the status bar at the top should be (480 - 20) / 4 = 115. Auto-layout seems to calculate 116.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a xib/storyboard? If you create the constraints by control-dragging between two views, they were probably created with their `constant` property set to whatever the offset of the views was at the time. Select each constraint and set its `constant` to `0` or whatever you want.

Comment: Yes they were created in storyboard. I control-dragged them, after the button widths were set to half the total width and aligned to the superview on both the sides. The constraints, thus, do have zero constant values. I might be able to figure out how to get the warning to go away with suitable constant values, but they should be zero IMHO.

Comment: Actually, the width warnings have gone now. Not sure what changed... I still have an issue with the height warnings. (480 - 20) / 4 = 115 ... misplaced views expects 116.